# Trying to fire off a bunch of onclicks all containing a different number

Tags: javascript, onclick

There is a page I can access that contains a bunch of links like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="navigate(___VIEW_RAID_2, {raid_inst_id:556816});return false;">
```

The number after the raid_inst_id: is always going to be different and there will be multiples on the same page all with different numbers. I'm trying to put together a javascript that will scrape the page for these links, put them in an array and then cycle through clicking them.

Ideally, an alert causing a pause between onclicks would be helpful. I've been unsuccessful so far even trying to gather the numbers and just echoing them out let alone manipulating them.

Any hints or help would be greatly appreciated!

Below is a function I tried putting together just to see if I could capture some of the onclick values for further processing but, this produces nothing...

```
function closeraids(){
        x=document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
        {
        attnode=x.item(i).getAttributeNode('onclick');
        alert("OnClick events are: " + attnode);
        }
}
```

---

Wow - 4 months later and the same problem still exists. I decided to look into this again only to find my own posted question in my Google search! Does anyone have any thoughts on what could be done here? The function I'm trying to provide will be part of a Chrome extension I already provide to users. It uses a combination of a .js file I host on my webserver and injected html content.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: What do you mean by "scrape" them? Do you have HTML strings, or is it already parsed to a DOM tree?

Comment: Sorry - scrape is probably the wrong word. The page is static but, unique to each visitor. Each visitor's version will have different values assigned through onclick events like my example. Normally, they would have to click on each of them 1 at a time to clear them out. I'd like to come up with a quicker more convenient way to go through all the onclick links.

Comment: lol - to answer your question - html strings

Comment: I'm no wiz at this obviously! I tried just a simple function to find all elements of a particular class and capture it's onclick attribute then echo it out to let me know if I even got anything but, the alerts just say null.

Answer (score 0):

Had some fun while making this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ralt/ttkGG/

Mostly because I went onto using almost fully functional style... but well. Onto your question.

I'm using `getAttribute('onclick')` to get the string in there. It shows something like:

```
"navigate(___VIEW_RAID_2, {raid_inst_id:553516});return false;"
```

So I just built the necessary regex to match it, and capture the number after `raid_inst_id`:

```
var re = /navigate\(___VIEW_RAID_2, {raid_inst_id:(\d+)}\);return false;/;
```

It's mostly rewriting the string by escaping the parentheses and putting `(\d+)` where you want to capture the number. (`\d+` is matching a number, `()` is capturing the matched string.)

Using `match()`, I can simply get the captured string as the last element. So, rewriting the code in old IE way:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
    re = /navigate\(___VIEW_RAID_2, {raid_inst_id:(\d+)}\);return false;/;

for (var i = 0, l = links.length; i < l; i++) {
    var attribute = links[i].getAttribute('onclick'),
        nb;

    if (nb = attribute.match(re)) {
        alert(nb.pop());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm.... strange. I tried implementing your example above by making a function out of it and including that in my js file. When I assign the function to a button and try it it just returns a bunch of popups stating "OnClick events are: null[object NodeList]